# Modify existing PHP code to delete file if it exists?

Tags: php, joomla

I have been trying to modify this function to delete a file if it already exists but it isn't working, it still creates a new file with a number in (). I have tried including the following:

```
$exists_file = $upload_dir.$uploaded_file;
if file_exists($exists_file) {
unlink($exists_file);
}
```

But it just stops the file from being uploaded at all. I'm still learning php and i really want to fix this. My basic aim is to overwrite existing files, rather than append a number to the end if the file already exists.

```
    protected function handle_file_upload($uploaded_file, $name, $size, $type, $error,
            $index = null, $content_range = null) {
            $file = new stdClass();
            $file->name = $this->get_file_name($name, $type, $index, $content_range);
            $file->size = $this->fix_integer_overflow(intval($size));
            $file->type = $type;
            if ($this->validate($uploaded_file, $file, $error, $index)) {
                $this->handle_form_data($file, $index);
                $upload_dir = $this->get_upload_path();
                if (!is_dir($upload_dir)) {
                    mkdir($upload_dir, $this->options['mkdir_mode'], true);
                }
                $file_path = $this->get_upload_path($file->name);
                $append_file = $content_range && is_file($file_path) &&
                    $file->size > $this->get_file_size($file_path); 
                 //Tried my code here
                 $exists_file = $upload_dir.$uploaded_file;
                if file_exists($exists_file) {
                unlink($exists_file);
                    }     
                if ($uploaded_file && is_uploaded_file($uploaded_file)) {
                    // multipart/formdata uploads (POST method uploads)
                    if ($append_file) {
                        file_put_contents(
                            $file_path,
                            fopen($uploaded_file, 'r'),
                            FILE_APPEND
                        );
                    } else {
                        move_uploaded_file($uploaded_file, $file_path);
                    }
                } else {
                    // Non-multipart uploads (PUT method support)
                    file_put_contents(
                        $file_path,
                        fopen('php://input', 'r'),
                        $append_file ? FILE_APPEND : 0
                    );
                }
                $file_size = $this->get_file_size($file_path, $append_file);
                if ($file_size === $file->size) {
                    $file->url = $this->get_download_url($file->name);
                    list($img_width, $img_height) = @getimagesize($file_path);
                    if (is_int($img_width) &&
                            preg_match($this->options['inline_file_types'], $file->name)) {
                        $this->handle_image_file($file_path, $file);
                    }
                } else {
                    $file->size = $file_size;
                    if (!$content_range && $this->options['discard_aborted_uploads']) {
                        unlink($file_path);
                        $file->error = 'abort';
                    }
                }
                $this->set_additional_file_properties($file);
            }
            return $file;
        }
```

Any ideas?

Best Regards
Donna

Comment: where in your method are you using that `if ( file_exists() )` code?

Comment: You want to inmediatly unlink the same file that is created? or you want certain named files that are saved to be deleted?

Comment: @CodeGodie i tried it after $file->size > $this->get_file_size($file_path);

Comment: @Dtorr1981 update your code and place the code you tried. You can use comments to show where you have tried. You can update your original post by clicking the _"edit"_ link

Comment: @baboizk I am uploading a file with the same name of an existing file. The existing file is located in $upload_dir. The uploaded file will therefore have the same filename, so before i move the uploaded file to the destination (where currently it see's the file already exists and puts (1) on the end) i want to check and delete it first.

Comment: @CodeGodie i have added the code. Just out of interest, as this is running within joomla, is there anyway i can get the variable values? I can't echo them as the code is initiated from the admin panel.

Comment: what do you get when you do `var_dump($exists_file);` after creating `$exists_file` ?

Comment: @CodeGodie i do not see anything at all, where would that output go? This function is part of a joomla component which currently appends rather than overwrites, so i'm not sure var_dump() will display anything as i have to run the code through the joomla admin GUI.